# Sort scala arrayBuffer of TimeStamp

Tags: scala, timestamp

I have this function:

```
def getTime() : ArrayBuffer[Timestamp] = {
    val offset = Timestamp.valueOf("2015-01-01 00:00:00").getTime()
    val end = Timestamp.valueOf("2015-01-02 00:00:00").getTime()
    val diff = end - offset + 1

    val mList = ArrayBuffer[Timestamp]()

    val numRecords = 3
    var i = 0
    while (i < numRecords) {
      val rand = new Timestamp(offset + (Math.random() * diff).toLong)

      mList += rand
      i += 1
    }

  //  mList.toList.sortWith(_ < _); 
   // scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(mList.toArray);
}
```

I have tried to sort the array but could not. I get this error:

```
No implicit Ordering defined for java.sql.Timestamp.
```

I know I need to define how the ordering would be done. Is there a way to sort it easily as in Java: Collections.sort(list);
or there is a better approach using Scala?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alternatively, define it somewhere in your class and you're good to go:

```
implicit def ordered: Ordering[Timestamp] = new Ordering[Timestamp] {
    def compare(x: Timestamp, y: Timestamp): Int = x compareTo y
}
getTime().sorted // now this will work just fine
```

Comment: Thanks Om, I would like to know how the implicit fun is connected to sorted? The concept behind?

Comment: @aselims oh, sorry for leaving it in a mist. If you take a look at how sorted is defined, you'll see that it implicitly requires one argument -- ordering, which  has to be defined somewhere in the scope. For many datatypes there is already such definition, provided by [scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L162) so you don't have to make extra work in order to work, some types, though, still require you to do manual wiring. Here, I defined such Ordering for Timestamp, making use of the fact that Timestamp is actually Comparable.

Comment: Note also, that `def ordered ....; getTime().sorted(ordered)` will work too, I simply added a bit magic.

Comment: Thanks @Om, would you provide me a brief reference that i can get such secrets of scala?

Comment: @aselims not quite brief, but canonical "Programming Scala" is a real deal

Answer (score 7):

```
mList.sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 1)
```

Note that's with an anonymous function, you could pass an explicit function, which would look like this:

```
def comparator(first: Timestamp, second: Timestamp) = first.compareTo(second) < 1

mList.sortWith(comparator)
```

There's no implicit ordering on Timestamp itself, here we're just sorting using the `compareTo` method.

Thanks to @Nick for pointing out sorting on `getTime()` wasn't suffient in all scenarios. I also looked at the `before` method which you would expect to work, but this only compares using the epoch value as well.

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` can represent time up to the nanosecond but `Timestamp.getTime` has a resolution of milliseconds, which leads to incorrect ordering of Timestamps that are less than 1ms apart, which is not too terribly uncommon if your timestamps are coming from Postgres etc.

Comment: @Nick good point, although Postgres only supports microsecond precision currently (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) as do most databases. But it would still be neater if the ordering was correct in every case. I'll see if I can work that into the answer.

Comment: Yep!  Anything less than millisecond resolution will trigger it in the `getTime` approach, since microseconds etc past the millsecond all get stored in the nanos component. (This recently bit me in the butt in some automated tests). Upvoted for the update :)

Comment: @Nick oh right, I just confused micro and milli there  either way it’s good to avoid any problems. Bit of a tricky class though.